# How to delete individual line of string from text API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

currently I have developed a LAME server that run the Sweet-Board application. The process is very simple but one issue; if a **user** was to send an inappropriate message, I want to make sure it gets deleted quick. So i've developed a delete button within the .php file that handles incoming messages, but once the button is pressed; it deletes every txt msg sent on the screen. How can I make it so that it only deletes **one message** instead of multiple ones. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Note: Solution has *not* been found yet.

(can find more info here: https://github.com/barrel/sweet-board)

Code:

```
    <?php
    require('twilio.php');
    include('config.php');
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
    $textcount=0;

    foreach ($client->account->sms_messages as $message) {
        $status= $message->status;
        if ($status=='received'){
            $time = date('c', strtotime($message->date_created));
            $body = $message->body;
            $smsid= $message->sid;  
    ?>
    <article <?php if ($textcount >= 6){ ?>class="hidden" <?php } ?>data-sid="<? 
    php echo $smsid; ?>">
        <blockquote>
          <p><em>&#8220;</em><?php echo $body; ?><em>&#8221;</em></p>
        </blockquote>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  

      <button>Delete</button>
     <script>
     $( "button" ).click(function() {
     $( "blockquote" ).remove();
     });
        </script>
     <abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $time; ?>"></abbr>
    </article>
    <?php
        $textcount++;
        }
      }
     ?>

   </style> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: `$( "blockquote" ).slice(-1).remove();`

Comment: This is close, however it still deletes every message off the board. I know there's a way to do this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specify ids for your blockquotes

```
<blockquote id='id_<?php echo $smsid;?>"></blockquote>


<button data-blockId="id_<?php echo $smsid;?>">Delete</button>


$("button").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('blockId'):
    $("#"+id).remove();
});
```

And button click javascript code will be better if it's out of foreach.